# OpenStack AutoPilot failing at 98%

Tags: maas, openstack, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to deploy OpenStack using Landscape's Autopilot. I get no errors till the final steps but after reaching 98% of the install two tasks fail to completed.

The two tasks that never reach completeion are:

"Add ubuntu-12.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1 to Glance"
"Add ubuntu-14.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1 to Glance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those images are downloaded from the Internet to make Ubuntu available in the Horizon dashboard to launch cloud instances with. Autopilot is trying to put them in place before your first login.

Can your newfangled OpenStack setup connect to the Internet?